# Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension

Tags: centos6, mariadb, litespeed

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

This is what I get when I try to install WP.

The server is running.

> Centos 6.7 x64.
>   Litespeed Standard Edition.
>   MariaDB.

I learned that php-mysql is required.
So I installed php-mysql.

```
# rpm -qa | grep php-mysql
php-mysql-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64

# tail mysqli.ini
; Enable mysqli extension module
extension=mysqli.so
```

Also in `phpinfo()` I have this.

```
Loaded Configuration File (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)
Additional .ini files parsed (none)
```

Do I need to rebuild PHP? Am I missing anything else?

Comment: Are you using the CentOS 6 php or have you installed a later version from source?

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not parsing the configuration file.
You could add

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

to your php.ini file. You can find php.ini by typeing the following command in terminal or by simply looking for the information in your phpinfo() file.

```
$ php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

(not including the "$")

Comment: I have updated the php.ini file. However in phpinfo() it's still not updated (I have rebooted litespeed) Loaded Configuration File  (none)

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that in phpinfo Configuration File (php.ini) Path  /usr/local/lib  But my php.ini is located at /etc/php.ini

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8q6lot

Comment: It might just be a symlink. But try to make the changes in /usr/local/lib/php.ini if that is the path reported by PHP.

Comment: To check if `/etc/php.ini` is a symlink, try: `cd /etc && ls -l php.ini`.

Comment: there is no file as /usr/local/lib/php.ini

Comment: And /etc/php.ini is not a symlink

Comment: what is the output of `php --ini` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30152/discussion-between-himanshu-and-nstensen).

Comment: PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqli' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php.d/json.ini,
/etc/php.d/memcache.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php.d/phar.ini,
/etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini,
/etc/php.d/zip.ini

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the php-fastcgi service:

`systemctl restart php-fastcgi`

Or the php-fpm service:

`systemctl restart php-fpm`

Comment: systemctl restart php5-fpm in this case possibly